# $f:P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$ , $f(A) = \{a_{1}+a_{2} | a_{1},a_{2}\in A\}$. Is $f$ injective/surjective?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Let $\mathbb N = \{0, 1, 2, \cdots \}$. Let $f$ be a function $f:P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$ defined by 
$$f(A) = \begin{cases} \varnothing & \text{if }A = \varnothing \\ 
\{a_{1}+a_{2} | a_{1},a_{2}\in A\}& \text{if }A\neq \varnothing.\end{cases}$$

e.g. we have $f(\{1,4\}) = \{2,5,8\}$.

Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ surjective?

In my opinion, $f$ is injective, but is not surjective.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove it, can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think of $f(\mathbb{N})$ and $f(\mathbb{N}\setminus \{5\})$ ?

Comment: Sorry,Didnt understand your question.

Comment: Well, it's a hint, can you compute these two sets and deduce something about $f$ ?

Comment: I got you,
$f(\mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: The special case for the empty set is unnecessary; it just specifies what the general definition would also have specified.

Comment: with your definition, is $0\in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

(Getting another old question off the unanswered list.)

The only ways to express $1$ as the sum of two (not necessarily distinct) non-negative integers are $1=0+1$ and $1=1+0$, so if $1\in f(A)$, then $0,1\in A$, and therefore $0=0+0\in f(A)$ and $2=1+1\in f(A)$. Thus, if $1\in f(A)$, then $f(A)\supseteq\{0,1,2\}$, so there is no $A\in\wp(\Bbb N)$ such that $f(A)=\{1\}$; this shows that $f$ is indeed not surjective.

Suppose that $0\in A\subseteq\Bbb N$; then $a=a+0\in f(A)$ for each $a\in A$, so $A\subseteq f(A)$. In particular, $\Bbb N\subseteq f(\Bbb N)\subseteq\Bbb N$, so $f(\Bbb N)=\Bbb N$. Let $n$ be any integer greater than $1$, and let $A=\Bbb N\setminus\{n\}$; $0\in A$, so $A\subseteq f(A)$. Moreover, $1,n-1\in A$, so $n=1+(n-1)\in f(A)$, $f(A)=\Bbb N=f(\Bbb N)$, and $f$ fails badly to be injective.